# php or html show POST from textarea

Tags: php, html

I have a textarea with text entered on multiple lines.

I submit that using POST to my PHP file...but there are problems.  I think they are to do with \n and \r in the text area because I am using "enter" to make a new line.

Is there a way using PHP or html I can see what exactly the POST is sending to my php, including the \n and other extra things?

Comment: Why not just use `echo "<pre>"; print_r(_$POST); echo "</pre>";` inside our PHP?

Comment: You could loop through the posted data and use ord() and check for 10 (new line) or 13 (carriage return). I think you should enumerate what the problems are. I would be surprised if it was \r or \n causing it.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try removing the \r and \n with something like:

```
$string = str_replace("\r\n",'',$string);
```

Firebug is also a good tool to see what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Check the function [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php).